# What is causing this Typescrip Error with SX prop

Tags: typescript, material-ui, sx

I got this example form here https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/ but I get this error from typescript.

```
sx={(theme: Theme): SxProps<Theme> | undefined => ({
  ...theme.typography.body,
  color: theme.palette.primary.main,
})}
```

```
Type '(theme: Theme) => SxProps<Theme> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.
  Type '(theme: Theme) => SxProps<Theme> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CSSSelectorObject<Theme>'.
    Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '(theme: Theme) => SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.ts(2322)
StatusBar.component.tsx(46, 12): Did you mean to call this expression?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by MUI team here is the thread. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29775

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You can write without Type declaration.

```
  <Box
     sx={(theme) => ({
       ...theme.typography.body1,
       color: theme.palette.primary.main,
     })}>
            <h1>Something</h1>
   </Box>
```

This will work perfectly fine (for Typescript), if you App component wrapped with ThemeProvider.

Comment: When I try this I get two error the first is
```
Parameter 'theme' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Comment: I also get this error No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & SystemProps<Theme> & { children?: ReactNode; component?: ElementType<any> | undefined; ref?: Ref<...> | undefined; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type '(theme: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'SxProps<Theme> | undefined'.